# Microsoft Excel Data Connections - Alter Connection String through VBA

Tags: vba, excel, odbc, connection-string

I have a fairly straightforward question. I am trying to find a way to alter and change a connection string for an existing data connection in an excel workbook through VBA (macro code). The main reason I am trying to do this is to find a way to prompt the user that opens up the workbook to enter their credentials (Username/Password) or have a checkbox for Trusted Connection that would be used in the Connection String of those existing data connections.

[image: Data Connection Properties]

Right now the Data connections are running off a sample user that I created and that needs to go away in the production version of the workbook. Hope that makes sense?

Is this possible? If yes, could you please give me a sample/example code block? I would really appreciate any suggestions at this point.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819 is probably a place to start.

Comment: we dont just give code... a suggestion would be to use workbook_open sub to show an userform or inputboxes asking for the credentials. saving it into the global variables then using them in the connection string.

Comment: @mehow I understand, I never asked for a direct solution. I was asking for examples of similar cases. I'm sorry if that offended you.

Secondly, I want to do what you mentioned, but that's not the issue I'm having. I am looking for a way to EDIT the EXISTING connection string of a data connection that I have setup (see screenshot above). I hope that helps?

Thanks much,
Pranav

Comment: @SillyCoda you have to decide if you want to use the excel UI or the VBA. Your title says `through` vba but you are demonstrating a screenshot from the UI. On top of your decision - it would have been too advanced for you to interact with the UI so I am strongly advising to use VBA

Comment: I have around 10 different connections setup already through the UI. We realized now that we will be needing the users to login to get access to the data through the ODBC. Hence, to do that behind the scenes, I was wondering if there is a way to modify an existing ODBC connection string to change the user credentials used to login from the UI via VBA code. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

I also had this exact same requirement and although the duplicate question [Excel macro to change external data query connections - e.g. point from one database to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708086/excel-macro-to-change-external-data-query-connections-e-g-point-from-one-data) was useful, I still had to modify it to meet the exact requirements above. I was working with a specific connection, while that answer targeted multiple connections. So, I've included my workings here. Thank you [@Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8479/rory) for his code.

Also thanks to [Luke Maxwell](http://uk.queryclick.com/seo-news/authors/LukeMaxwell/) for his function to [search a string for matching keywords](http://uk.queryclick.com/seo-news/searching-string-list-matches-excel/).

Assign this sub to a button or call it when the spreadsheet is opened.

```
Sub GetConnectionUserPassword()
  Dim Username As String, Password As String
  Dim ConnectionString As String
  Dim MsgTitle As String
  MsgTitle = "My Credentials"

  If vbOK = MsgBox("You will be asked for your username and password.", vbOKCancel, MsgTitle) Then
      Username = InputBox("Username", MsgTitle)
          If Username = "" Then GoTo Cancelled
          Password = InputBox("Password", MsgTitle)
          If Password = "" Then GoTo Cancelled
  Else
  GoTo Cancelled
  End If

    ConnectionString = GetConnectionString(Username, Password)
    ' MsgBox ConnectionString, vbOKOnly
    UpdateQueryConnectionString ConnectionString
    MsgBox "Credentials Updated", vbOKOnly, MsgTitle
  Exit Sub
Cancelled:
  MsgBox "Credentials have not been changed.", vbOKOnly, MsgTitle
End Sub
```

The GetConnectionString function stores the connection string that you insert your username and password into. This one is for an OLEDB connection and is obviously different depending on the requirements of the Provider.

```
Function GetConnectionString(Username As String, Password As String)

  Dim result As Variant

  result = "OLEDB;Provider=Your Provider;Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DATABASE" _
    & ";User ID=" & Username & ";Password=" & Password & _
    ";Persist Security Info=True;Extended Properties=" _
    & Chr(34) & "PORT=1706;LOG=ON;CASEINSENSITIVEFIND=ON;INCLUDECALCFIELDS=ON;" & Chr(34)

  ' MsgBox result, vbOKOnly
  GetConnectionString = result
End Function
```

This code does the job of actually updating a named connection with your new connection string (for an OLEDB connection).

```
Sub UpdateQueryConnectionString(ConnectionString As String)

  Dim cn As WorkbookConnection
  Dim oledbCn As OLEDBConnection
  Set cn = ThisWorkbook.Connections("Your Connection Name")
  Set oledbCn = cn.OLEDBConnection
  oledbCn.Connection = ConnectionString

End Sub
```

Conversely, you can use this function to get whatever the current connection string is.

```
Function ConnectionString()

  Dim Temp As String
  Dim cn As WorkbookConnection
  Dim oledbCn As OLEDBConnection
  Set cn = ThisWorkbook.Connections("Your Connection Name")
  Set oledbCn = cn.OLEDBConnection
  Temp = oledbCn.Connection
  ConnectionString = Temp

End Function
```

I use this sub to refresh the data when the workbook is opened but it checks that there is a username and password in the connection string before doing the refresh. I just call this sub from the Private Sub Workbook_Open().

```
Sub RefreshData()
    Dim CurrentCredentials As String
    Sheets("Sheetname").Unprotect Password:="mypassword"
    CurrentCredentials = ConnectionString()
    If ListSearch(CurrentCredentials, "None", "") > 0 Then
        GetConnectionUserPassword
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("My Connection Name").Refresh
    Sheets("Sheetname").Protect _
    Password:="mypassword", _
    UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
    AllowFiltering:=True, _
    AllowSorting:=True, _
    AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
End Sub
```

Here is the ListSearch function from Luke. It returns the number of matches it has found.

```
Function ListSearch(text As String, wordlist As String, seperator As String, Optional caseSensitive As Boolean = False)
  Dim intMatches As Integer
  Dim res As Variant
  Dim arrWords() As String
  intMatches = 0
  arrWords = Split(wordlist, seperator)
  On Error Resume Next
  Err.Clear
  For Each word In arrWords
      If caseSensitive = False Then
          res = InStr(LCase(text), LCase(word))
      Else
          res = InStr(text, word)
      End If
      If res > 0 Then
          intMatches = intMatches + 1
      End If
  Next word
  ListSearch = intMatches
End Function
```

Finally, if you want to be able to remove the credentials, just assign this sub to a button.

```
Sub RemoveCredentials()
  Dim ConnectionString As String
  ConnectionString = GetConnectionString("None", "None")
  UpdateQueryConnectionString ConnectionString
  MsgBox "Credentials have been removed.", vbOKOnly, "Your Credentials"
End Sub
```

Hope this helps another person like me that was looking to solve this problem quickly.