# VBA Code - change OLEDB connection

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a button within Excel which is supposed to change the connection string (to SQL Server) according to few parameters entered on a specific excel sheet. I have came across this link 
[Excel macro to change external data query connections - e.g. point from one database to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708086/excel-macro-to-change-external-data-query-connections-e-g-point-from-one-data)

I concluded the following but it is not working

```
Sub GetConnections()
    Dim ConnectionString
    ConnectionString = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=.;UID=sa;PWD=123;APP=Microsoft Office 2013;WSID=MachineID;DATABASE=X"

    Dim w As Worksheet
    Dim cn As WorkbookConnection
    Dim OdbcCn As ODBCConnection
    For Each cn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
        Set OdbcCn = cn.ODBCConnection
        OdbcCn.SavePassword = True
        OdbcCn.Connection = ConnectionString

    Next
MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

When I run the code above, I get
Run Time error (1004):
Application-defined or object-defined error

The debugger highlights this "OdbcCn.Connection = ConnectionString"

Your help is highly appreciated,