# Excel VBA change just the Server name in all data connections in a workbook

Tags: vba, excel, data-connections

Good Afternoon All,

I have been looking at various ways to change/update the data connection strings in a workbook to update the Server name only and keep the other parts of the string as they are.

Basically we have migrated servers and the server name has change and now we have a number of reports that need updating. Some have multiple connections as they connect to different databases.

I found a useful article but this replaces the string with a completely new one for all the data connections (which doesnt work due to the different databases)
[excel-macro-to-change-external-data-query-connections-e-g-point-from-one-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708086/excel-macro-to-change-external-data-query-connections-e-g-point-from-one-data)

Has anyone had to go through this process and found a way of easily updating the connection string?

Kind Regards

Comment: Are you building the DB connections in your code?

Comment: your question and the content seem to be contradicting. Server change or Database change?

Comment: Sorry I meant just the server name.

Comment: The connections are not built/defined in VBA.

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming the database names havent changed, but just the server, will the below work for you. Not tested

```
Sub ChangeAllConnections()

    Dim q As QueryTable, w As Worksheet, oldserverName As String, newServerName  As String
    Dim con As Variant

    oldserverName = "onlsrvr" 'Change here
    newServerName = "newsrvr" ' change here

    For Each w In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      For Each q In w.QueryTables
        q.Connection = Replace(q.Connection, oldserverName, newServerName)
      Next
    Next

    On Error Resume Next
     For Each con In ThisWorkbook.Connections
        con.ODBCConnection.Connection = Replace(con.ODBCConnection.Connection, oldserverName, newServerName)
        con.OLEDBConnection.Connection = Replace(con.OLEDBConnection.Connection, oldserverName, newServerName)
      Next
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems to run with no errors but the connections havent updated.

Comment: can you put a breakpoint on q.connection =... and see if the replace happened there correctly

Comment: It doesnt seem to hit that line of code. When I watch through step through it jumps from Fro Each q.... down to Next... and goes through this process until its gone through each worksheet.

Comment: please try my EDIT- it worked on both sheet level query tables and connections in the workbook

Answer (score 1):

I would consider placing things like this in an sameNameAsWorkbook.ini file. Keep the file in the same location as the Workbook.  Then have your code read the ini file and build the connection that way.  Then if it needs to change you can change it in one spot very easily.