# excel macro to change external data query connections

Tags: vba, excel

I found the following response and it looks like it could potentially work but as the last comment says, it breaks when running in excel 2013.

[Excel macro to change external connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708086/excel-macro-to-change-external-data-query-connections-e-g-point-from-one-data)

The spot that I am getting an error on is

```
odbcCn.Connection = ConnectionString
```

Comment: You can improve this question by adding the code you adapted from the other question.

Comment: what error are you getting?